# Reload Model On ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-click

**This is my HTML Code:**

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Angular App</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/angularJs-1.2.22/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/angularJs-1.2.22/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/angularJs-1.2.22/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/angularJs-1.2.22/angular-mocks.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/angularJs-1.2.22/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/angularJs-1.2.22/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/angularJs-1.2.22/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/angularJs-1.2.22/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/angularJs-1.2.22/i18n/angular-locale_fr-fr.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/controller.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/directives/directive.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/filters/filter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/services/service.js"></script>

<!-- flatUI -->
<!-- Loading Bootstrap -->
<link href="resources/flatUI/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="resources/flatUI/bootstrap/css/prettify.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Loading Flat UI -->
<link href="resources/flatUI/css/flat-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="resources/flatUI/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body ng-controller="defaultController">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr simple-repeater source="products" item-name="item">
                <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                <td>{{item.price | currency}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button class="btn btn-default text" ng-click="changeData()">Change</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is my controller:**

```
app.controller("defaultController", function($scope)
{
    $scope.dataSource= "controller";

    $scope.products = [{ name: "Apples", price: 1.20 },
                       { name: "Bananas", price: 2.42 }, 
                       { name: "Pears", price: 2.02 }];

    $scope.changeData = function()
    {
        var data = [{ name: "Apples1", price: 1.20 },
                       { name: "Bananas1", price: 2.42 }, 
                       { name: "Pears1", price: 2.02 }];

        $scope.products.length = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            $scope.products.push(data[i]);
        }
    }
})
```

**This is my directive:**

```
app.directive("simpleRepeater", function()
{
    return {
        scope: {
            data: "=source",
            propName: "@itemName"
        },
        transclude: 'element',
        compile: function(element, attrs, transcludeFn)
        {
            return function($scope, $element, $attr)
            {
                $scope.$watch("data.length", function()
                {
                    var parent = $element.parent();
                    parent.children().remove();
                    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.data.length; i++)
                    {
                        var childScope = $scope.$new();
                        childScope[$scope.propName] = $scope.data[i];
                        transcludeFn(childScope, function(clone)
                        {
                            parent.append(clone);
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
})
```

All I am tyring to do is reload my model on the click, ie all old data has to be removed and new data has to be loaded, can some one please tell me where exactly I am going wrong as the new data is not getting updated on the view, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`$watchCollection`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection) instead of `$watch`. In your case your array doesn't change the length, you want to detect its contents changes. So you need to watch array itself, not just length:

```
$scope.$watchCollection("data", function () {
    var parent = $element.parent();
    parent.children().remove();
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.data.length; i++) {
        var childScope = $scope.$new();
        childScope[$scope.propName] = $scope.data[i];
        transcludeFn(childScope, function (clone) {
            parent.append(clone);
        });
    }
});
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/6mbHQhLldf28BnFVaQu1?p=preview